# Which configuration is better in terms of elastic stiffness?

Tags: material-science, elasticity

[image]

Which one deforms more when subjected to the same torque? I am having trouble thinking about this  mathematically and with equations. Don't know what to do...

Comment: What are the boundary conditions and loads for this problem?

Comment: Maybe are you referring to a rod that is long compared with $D_0$ with a torque applied in the ends?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are talking about the twist of a slender bar.

In that case, you can consider that the torsional stiffness is written as

$$
\kappa_0 = J_0 G_0 + J_1 G_1 = \frac{\pi G_0 (r_1^4 -r_0^4)}{2} + \frac{\pi r_0^4\, G_1}{2}\, ,
$$

for one case, and

$$
\kappa_1 = J_0 G_1 + J_1 G_0 = \frac{\pi G_1 (r_1^4 -r_0^4)}{2} + \frac{\pi r_0^4\, G_0}{2}\, ,
$$

in the other.

Now, let us compare both of these

$$\kappa_r = \frac{\kappa_1}{\kappa_0} = \frac{G_1 r_1^4 - r_0^4 G_1 + G_0 r_0^4} {G_0 r_1^4 + r_0^4 G_1 -G_0 r_0^4}\, ,$$

and if we take the following limits,

\begin{align}
\lim_{G_1 \rightarrow \infty} = \frac{r_1^4 - r_0^4}{r_0^4}\, ,\\
\lim_{G_1 \rightarrow 0} = \frac{r_0^4}{r_1^4 - r_0^4}\, ,
\end{align}

we see that the stiffness is higher when the external part is stiffer.